# Any way to see key codes on linux without sudo

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, sudo, ubuntu-18.04

I have a managed computer (Ubuntu 18) and my sudo is limited. I want to do some key mapping for my keyboard, but I can't figure out what the key code is for the specific button.

The keyboard is a Keychron K10 (not exactly linux friendly), and it has a "microphone" key in place of Scroll Lock that's supposed to activate Cortana. I want to make it into ScLk in order to serve as my GtkComposeKey.

The trouble is, all the solutions I've seen require `sudo` to view which key is being pressed on the keyboard. Is there a non-sudo way, or should I request "sudoers" access to a particular executable?

Comment: What kind of keycodes do you want? Do you need scancodes for mapping via udev? Do you need evdev codes for mapping via interception-tools? Do you need X11 event codes for mapping via xmodmap? While it is true that some keycode types need root to obtain, this is generally only true for keycode types that would also need root to _use,_ while keycodes that can be remapped without privileges can be obtained the same way.

Comment: I'm using xmodmap but I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

To see keypress events, keycodes, keysyms and the results of XLookupString, you could use xev(1). Just start /usr/bin/xev on a command line, and try out the keys of your keyboard.  Altertnatively, you can install [xkeycaps](https://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/) to explore the mappings of your keyboard. To (re-)map keysyms, you can use xmodmap or xkeycaps.